# how to query date in json?

Tags: json, postgresql

```
create tabel test(json jsonb);
insert into test values('{"graductionDate": "Jun  1 2015 12:00AM"}')
insert into test values('{"graductionDate": "Jun  1 2016 12:00AM"}')
```

query result is incorrect:

```
select * from test where json>'{"graductionDate":"20151001 00:00"}'
```

I want get data with graductionDate after 20150101. But the above code gets all rows.

Comment: Could you give the result you expected, and the result you actually got?

Comment: I want  get  data after 20150101 .but use "select * from test where json>'{"graductionDate":"20151001 00:00"}'" get all data

Comment: Cool. I've edited that into your question for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Not having used json objects before I would *guess* you need to extract the date field from the object, treat it as a date and then compare it to another date.

```
select * 
  from test 
 where ((json->>'graductionDate')::timestamp) > ('20151001 00:00':: timestamp);
```

*I havent tested this code.*

---

**Edit**

From your comment it sounds like the `->>` operator treats `null` as the empty string `''`.  You can convert `''` to `null` using the `nullif()` function:

```
select * 
  from test 
 where (nullif(json->>'graductionDate', '')::timestamp) > ('20151001 00:00':: timestamp);
```

*This code is still untested.*

Comment: code doesn't work. `ERROR:  cannot cast type jsonb to timestamp without time zone
LINE 3:  where ((json->'graductionDate')::timestamp) >'20151001 00:0...
`

Comment: hmm. guessing that needs the `->>` instead of `->`

Comment: yeah, that fixed it,

Comment: another problem: if the relust value is null . can't execute this query.ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""